# Terraform - Protocol error when using Heredoc in local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform, heredoc, hcl

I'm using a heredoc to allow for multiple lines in a Terraform local-exec provisioner. For some reason when I use `>` to create a new file I'm getting a `Protocal error`.

I've tried wrapping it with single/double qoutes, but that did not work. However it does work as a single line command. `command = "> foo"`

How can I use `>` in a Terraform heredoc?

System Info:

```
[vagrant@rhel7 terraform-main]$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.7
+ provider.aws v2.27.0
```

HCL:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      > foo
    EOT
  }
```

Output:

```
Error: Error running command '      > foo
: Protocol error. Output: /bin/sh: foo
```

It looks like `foo` is being treated as a command...

I notice that `touch` has similar results.

```
command = <<EOT
  touch foo
EOT
```

Output:

```
Error: Error running command '      touch foo
': exit status 1. Output: touch: cannot touch ‘foo\r’: Protocol error
```

Comment: For the first error, your shell interpreter would treat `foo` as a command in that case.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, So how can I create a file in a heredoc?

Comment: This would be much easier: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/r/file.html

Comment: @MattSchuchard, that will not work because the file I'm creating is an inventory file used to provision this resource. There would be a cyclic dependency.